# Example for vtkContourGrid

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to make contour plot from unstructured grid. My code does not work and I could not find an example to follow. I did not include the input file, hoping that a sample unstructured grid is easy to find. I managed to make work on Paraview by converting cell data to point data and then contouring "p" scalar. But I cannot do it with vtk. What's wrong in my code?

```
from vtk import *

file_name = "results.vtk"

reader = vtkUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName(file_name)
reader.Update() 
output = reader.GetOutput()
scalar_range = output.GetScalarRange()

c2p = vtkCellDataToPointData()
c2p.SetInputData(output)

contours = vtkContourGrid()
contours.SetInputData(c2p.GetOutput())
contours.SetValue(0, 0.007009505294263363)

gridmapper = vtkDataSetMapper()
gridmapper.SetInputData(output)
gridmapper.GetInput().GetCellData().SetActiveScalars("p")
gridmapper.SetScalarVisibility(1)
gridmapper.SetScalarRange(scalar_range)

mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
#mapper = vtkDataSetMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(contours.GetOutputPort())

actor = vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

gridactor = vtkActor()
gridactor.SetMapper(gridmapper)
gridactor.GetProperty().EdgeVisibilityOn()

renderer = vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.AddActor(gridactor)
#renderer.SetBackground(1, 1, 1) # Set background to white

renderer_window = vtkRenderWindow()
renderer_window.AddRenderer(renderer)

interactor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(renderer_window)
interactor.Initialize()
interactor.Start()
```

Comment: is there a `SetInputConnection` instead of the `SetInputData` in python ? In c++ this avoid some update related troubles.

Comment: I don't know but you can provide a working c++ version of this code if you want.